# WinSCP batch file not working but manually work in CMD

Tags: batch-file, winscp

My Script:

```
cd C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\WinSCP-5.9.2-Portable

winscp.com /command ^
"open ftp://test:TESTT@ftp.abc.com" 
"cd /facommon" ^
"get file.*gz" ^
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you are missing a caret `^` at the end of this line:

```
"open ftp://test:TESTT@ftp.abc.com"
```

You can verify the method is actually working with this public FTP:

```
cd C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\WinSCP-5.9.2-Portable

winscp.com /command ^
    "open ftp://anonymous:password@ftp.mirror.nl/" ^
    "cd /pub/test/" ^
    "get *.html" ^
    "exit"
```

[Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl) (Author of [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/)) pointed to WinSCP's documentation in this regard:

- [Why are some scripting commands specified on WinSCP command-line in a batch file not executed/failing?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_batch_file)

He also added that an `exit` statement should be present at the end.

Comment: @RaghunathKurup: The caret `^` is outside of the quotes and shouldn't be interpreted by WinSCP at all - are you pasting this into the WinSCP shell like [so](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13763)? That's not how it's supposed to work... Does my example work if you put it in a `.bat` batch file?